# How can I use the Spring @Pattern annotation to force the string to comply to one of the regexes, but not all at the same time?

Tags: java, spring, validation

I don't want to have several regexes that all have to be fulfilled. Rather, I would like that only one of the regexes provided are valid, not the others. An example could be that I want a string to fulfill the demands for either an IP on V4 format or V6 format, but not both at the same time.

```
@Pattern(regexp = ipV4)
@Pattern(regexp = ipV6)
String ipAddress;
```

Answer (score 0):

A naive solution is to change the regex to match several alternatives:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "ipV4|ipV6")
String ipAddress;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I would prefer a Spring way to do it, but I see how this will work as well :)